# Supporting the "with open" syntax without using contextlib.closing()

Tags: python

I really like the syntax "with open('in_file'') as f".
I want to use that syntax for my own resources which must be opened and closed.

However, I do not understand how to change my open() method to enable the 'with' syntax.
I can (and do) use the contextlib.closing() approach but it becomes a bit bulky after repeated use.

So, I will ask my question below in relation to shelve.open().
I am not proposing a change to the shelve module but instead am using it because the source code is readily available to all of you.

There is nothing special about shelve.open() vs. other standard library resources that require closing: socket.socket(), sqlite3.connect(), urllib2.urlopen(), etc.

```
import contextlib, inspect, shelve, sys

#print(inspect.getsource(open))  # can not see how it was done here :-(

print('-' * 40)
# Given that we can view the source for the shelve module:
print(inspect.getsource(shelve))

print('-' * 40)
# Given that we can view the docs for the shelve module:
print(shelve.__doc__)

#print('-' * 40)
# Given that the desired syntax is Pythonic but is not supported:
#with shelve.open('test_shelve') as my_shelve:
#    my_shelve['fact_number_1'] = "There's a dead fish on the landing."

# Given that the required syntax is convoluted and
#    takes programmer attention away from the task at hand:
with contextlib.closing(shelve.open('test_shelve')) as my_shelve:
    my_shelve['fact_number_2'] = "There's another dead fish on the landing."

# Q: What changes would need to made to shelve.open() to allow the
#    'with shelve.open(x) as y' syntax?
```

I am not really interested in an extra wrapper with a different name. Using contextlib.closing() is easier, safer, and more intuitive than that. What I am really interested in is creating a single open() method that can be called either with or without 'with'.

So, to successfully answer this question, you need to take the source code for the shelve module and show what changes would need to be made to shelve.open() to have a single method that can be used either with or without 'with' (like the builtin open() or the Python3 urllib.urlopen()).

Comment: Basically whatever you have after the `with` has to have an `__exit__` method that does whatever needs to be done when the `with` block is finished. `contextlib.closing()` just adds a wrapper which has an `__exit__` method that calls `.close()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that if you do

```
shelf = the_function_you_want()
```

the function you want has to return the shelf, but if you do

```
with the_function_you_want() as shelf:
```

the function you want has to return a context manager. That means you need to return a shelf that is also a context manager, which in turn means you either need to make a shelf subclass or monkey-patch `Shelf`. It's probably better to make a subclass:

```
class ContextManagerShelf(shelve.DbfilenameShelf):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        self.close()
```

Then you can use `ContextManagerShelf` as a context manager or not. The signature is the same as `shelve.open`. If you want, you can also make an `open` function to go with it.

Comment: Given what you have said here, how were the builtin open() or the Python3 urllib.open() created?  With these two, you have a single method that can be called either with or without 'with'.

Comment: @cclauss: File objects implement the context manager protocol, just like the `ContextManagerShelf` I just wrote. You can use them directly, or you can use them in a `with` statement, where their `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods will do the right thing. I can edit a description of how context managers work into the answer.

Comment: @cclauss: It might be simpler to just link to [existing](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) [explanations](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), though.

Comment: Awesome!! Just by adding your __enter__() and __exit__() methods above to the class DbfilenameShelf, I got all the functionality that I was looking for.  A very elegant solution to my question.  Thx.

Comment: @cclauss: You modified `DbfilenameShelf` directly? Be careful with that, or some day in the future, you'll be very confused when the code you've been relying on stops working when you run it on someone else's machine.

Comment: Understood...  I did it to a copy with a different name (shelve_supporting_with_open.py) just so I could learn how it all works.  Thanks much for your guidance.